# GoLand proxy setting intercepts vpn connect after grpc update from 1.31 to 1.41

Tags: go, grpc, etcd, goland

I was using goland 2022.3 on a windows 10 machine. I have been working on a project related to etcd and just updated from version 3.4 to 3.5 which also introduced a gRPC update from 1.3 to 1.4. However, I found out that when I tried to run the program in the editor, the etcd connection was not going through the vpn as it used to but was instead going through the goland proxy, resuling a connection timeout error. I was wandering if anyone encountered similiar problems and why my version update could affect the network connection setting.

I closed the goland proxy setting and the etcd connection works as beofore, which is,  going through the vpn